# python sympy cannot sub value when using letter I

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy expressions to rearrange and solve equations i have been given.

```
from sympy import *

V = symbols("V")
I = symbols("I")
R = symbols("R")
expr = "R*I-V"
expr = parse_expr(expr)

expr = expr.subs("I",20)
expr = expr.subs("R",10)

answer = solve(expr,V)
print(answer)
```

this should output 200 but insted outputs I*10

for some reason it does not substitute the value for I

when a differnt value is used it works fine:

```
V = symbols("V")
i = symbols("i")
R = symbols("R")
expr = "R*i-V"
expr = parse_expr(expr)

expr = expr.subs("i",20)
expr = expr.subs("R",10)

answer = solve(expr,V)
print(answer)
```

this outputs the correct value of 200
other values work such as other capitals and non capitals.

Could someone explain if there is something i have missed or if this behaviour is strange

as i mentioned before i tried using a different value and it worked as expected.

rearranging the entered equation did nothing so `expr = "R*I-V"` had the same output as `expr = "I*R-V"`

Comment: Why are you parsing strings? You could just write `expr = R*I - V; expr.subs(I, 20)` since your created value of `I` will override the value imported at the beginning (implicitly).

Answer (score 2):

Sympy uses some letters to identify specific objects. In particular:

- "O" is an alias to the `Order` class.
- "Q" is an alias for the `AssumptionKeys` class.
- "S" is an alias to the `sympify()` function, or to the registry of singleton objects.
- "N" is an alias to numerical evaluation with the `evalf()` function.
- "E" represents the base of the natural logarithm.
- "I" represents the imaginary unit.

Hence, when `parse_expr` sees the `"I"` character, it converts it to the imaginary unit! You can provide the `locad_dict` dictionary to associate your symbols to a particular character of the string. For example:

```py
expr = "R*I-V"
I = symbols("I")
expr = parse_expr(expr, local_dict={"I": I})

expr = expr.subs("I",20)
expr = expr.subs("R",10)

answer = solve(expr,V)
print(answer)
# [200]
```

Comment: I see thank you very much. if i was to only import a spesific part of sympy would that stop this issue from happening if that makes sense?

Comment: No it wouldn't, because this behavior is hard coded into sympy.